# How to center the image?

Tags: html, css

I have a background image of original size *1024 x 1024 pixel*. How can I center the image on the page? I want to apply the image on the complete body.

```
body {
  background-image:url('images/bg.jpg');
  height: 1024px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I was thinking of giving a left and right margin in pixels, but thought if there is a better way out, that is more exact.

Answer (score 0):

You mean :

```
body { 
  background-image:url('images/bg.jpg') no-repeat center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover; /* for Chrome and Safari */
  -moz-background-size: cover; /* for Firefox */
  -o-background-size: cover; /* for Opera */
  background-size: cover; /* standard */
}
```

Code article on [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: and the text or fields that will get inserted inside the body. They won't automatically come over the image, as if it was the beginning of the page

Answer (score 0):

You can align the background image in the center by using:

```
body {
  background: url('images/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  height: 1024px;
}
```